# Error Management in Genexus SD

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I am testing GX24 Android App, and have some questions related to how errors are managed:

- When the App can't connect to server we can see a nice managed message with an image, instead of the ordinary "Not connected" or "Timeout" blank panel. How can I customize my own error panel?

[image]

- When the App started for the first time, It took some 3 to 4 minutes retrieving data. I am used to "timeout" errors for such time demanding server-side operations (more than one minute). How can I "avoid" them?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You can check the network connection's status by using the [Network API](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?22526) external object:

```
&IsConnected = NetWorkAPI.IsServerAvailable()
if &isConnected
    ...
else
    NotConnectedSDPanel()
endif
```

2) Regarding the timeout, there is currently no way to configure it in your application. However, the Synchronization.Receive method is special in two ways:

1. It returns the synchronization data as a stream, so it only needs to start writing the response in less than a minute, but it can take longer to send all the information.
2. In iOS it has a timeout of ten minutes instead of one, as a normal procedure would, so the server can take longer to start responding. Not so in Android where the timeout is the one minute default.

Comment: Thanks for the very informative solution. Anyway, just to let you know, I did some tests (where I disconnected the server when the app was executing) and, in this scenario, the isServerAvailable method would still return a true, resulting in an unmanaged timeout error.

Comment: @Jaime, could you please send a support issue?